# Entity Framework Core saves single entity instead of updating

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

So I've been reading around, and it seems most issues regarding this is that you have to disjoint contexts, and the solution seems to normally be creating some foreign keys. However, my problem is on a single entity and not a relation to this entity, and I have the foreign keys I can come to think of as required. I think it has to do with using a GUID as primary key.

My entity of crime is:

```
public class Customer
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Organization> Organizations { get; set; }
}
```

It has been configured as follows with the fluent API:

```
    public override void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Customer> entity)
    {
        entity.HasKey(customer => customer.Id); // Primary key
        entity.Property(customer => customer.Name).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(255);
        entity.Property(customer => customer.CreatedAt).IsRequired();

        entity.HasMany(customer => customer.Organizations)
            .WithOne(organization => organization.Customer)
            .HasForeignKey(organization => organization.CustomerId);
    }
```

It generates the following SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE [Customer] (
    [Id] uniqueidentifier NOT NULL,
    [CreatedAt] datetime2 NOT NULL,
    [Name] nvarchar(255) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Customer] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
);
```

I save it with this code:

```
public class AddCustomer : ICommand
{
    public Guid CustomerId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[Transactional]
internal sealed class HandleAddCustomer : IHandleCommand<AddCustomer>
{
    private readonly IEntityWriter<Customer> _writer;
    public HandleAddCustomer(IEntityWriter<Customer> writer)
    {
        _writer = writer;
    }

    public Task HandleAsync(AddCustomer command)
    {
        var customer = new Customer
        {
            Id = command.CustomerId,
            Name = command.Name,
            CreatedAt = DateTime.Now
        };

        _writer.Save(customer);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

The entityWriter is a system we created for handling our database interactions more uniformly, it's a wrapper which supports Entity Framework and wraps it all with SimpleInjector and DI.

The parameter command is populatedfrom an API endpoint:

```
    [HttpPost("AddCustomer")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AddCustomer(AddCustomer customer)
    {
        await _commands.ExecuteAsync(customer);

        return Ok("Customer Saved");
    }
```

With the following payload:

```
{
    "CustomerId": "692da47a-3886-42bb-a1ac-d853d315109a",
    "Name": "Test Customer"
}
```

Which all works fine and dandy, until I send the same ID.

```
{
    "CustomerId": "692da47a-3886-42bb-a1ac-d853d315109a",
    "Name": "New name"
}
```

Then I get the a foreign key violation because it tries to insert it as a new row, which results in a duplicate primary key of course. So my culprit, i think, is the handling of the Id. I've seen people suggest

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
```

But my primary key is not generated by the database (comes from an existing disjoint system), so I just want it to adhere to the primary key and see that it's the same entity and it has to update it. Do I need to query the database first with some

`if(_queries<Customer>().Where(c => c.Id == command.Id).FirstOrDefault() != null) { ...//The customer already exists, update the name in the entity and save it again`

it just feels a bit spaghetti-codeish to manually check for an existing entity every time I execute a command, but albeit my experience with EF is limited (and EF Core especially), it might just be me expecting a bit too much from it.

**Edit:** I've been digging through some code written by a past employee, and it seems the EF integration (and particularly save) only sets the actual state of the entity:

```
 public void Save(TEntity entity)
        {
            var context = _contextProvider();
            var entry = context.Entry(entity);

            // If it is not tracked by the context, add it to the context
            if (entry.State == EntityState.Detached)
            {
                // This also sets the entity state to added.
                context.Set<TEntity>().Add(entity);
            }
            else
            {
                // Tells the context that the entity should be updated during saving changes
                entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
            }
        }
```

And then the Unit of Work is processed with SaveChangesAsync():

```
public async Task ExecuteAsync()
        {
            await _contextProvider().SaveChangesAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
```

But with regards to Frederik's suggestion, I might need to update the library to also use AddOrUpdate() *sneaky edit* which seems to not be implemented in EF Core yet. Yay.

Comment: Instead of _writer.Save(customer) have you tried with db.SaveChanges(); after change of your customer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a method called AddOrUpdate()

```
db.Customer.AddOrUpdate(customer);
```

That you can use. It's an extension method that you can find out more about here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh846520(v=vs.103).aspx

Comment: Unfortunately this is not yet implemented in EF Core, but I think the way to go is for me to create my own version for now.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to query the DB first if the ID already exists or not.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to change the implementation of: _writer.Save(customer);
It should look something like this:

```
public void Save(Customer customer)
{
   var dalCustomer = context.Customers.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id = entity.Id);
   if (dalCustomer == null)
   {
      dalCustomer = new Customer();
      context.Customers.Add(dalCustomer);
   }

   dalCustomer.Name = customer.Name;
   dalCustomer.CreatedAt = DateTime.Now;

   context.SaveChanges();
}
```

(This code is not tested or compiled)